# O que significa runtime dependencies of objects?

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Qual o significado de runtime dependencies of objects em programação orientada a objetos? Me deparei com essa questão estudando C++.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tradução de *runtime dependencies of objects* em escopo livre seria algo como "dependência de objetos em tempo de execução". Funciona da seguinte forma:

Em linguagens compiladas como C++, o compilador tem basicamente duas fases: a **compilação**, em que todas as classes e estruturas de dados são conferidas e seu código é transformado em código de máquina, e a **ligação**, onde as referências entre vários arquivos de objeto (ou os arquivos com código de máquina) são conferidas novamente pra ver se nada ficou faltando.

No caso de dependências em tempo de execução, possivelmente estamos falando de classes que estão implementadas em bibliotecas dinâmicas, normalmente fornecidas por terceiros. A conferência dessas dependências é feita quando seu programa executa. O tratamento de erros deve ser feito através do mecanismo de captura de exceções.